# Opencv doesn't work in Android - No implementation found for Mat

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, dependencies

I'm trying to do basic usage of OpenCv in android.

This is my main activity on create:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
    Mat image_mat = new Mat();
```

It fails:

```
No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
```

I've tried multiple HOW-TO opencv + android tutorials. It doesn't work for me.

I've downloaded opencv-4.4.0-android-sdk.
I've added the sdk/java directory as module dependency (after rename to the name "opencv"):
[image]

This is the start of my app build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

And this is my opencv module build gradle:

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
//    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
//        applicationId "org.opencv"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

That's my project structure (as you can see, added jnilibs under main):

[image]

I've also tried to add this:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

And then on onCreate():

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback);
}
```

It writes:

```
I/TFLiteExample: OpenCV loaded successfully
/TFLiteExample: Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing file of libopencv_java4.so in your subfolders under JNILIBS folder.  Assume that you want to support different platforms, this file can be put in each of the subfolders.  This will solve the problem.